# Sum values of arraylist in hashmap java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to sum values of `arraylist` in `hashmap java`. Following is my code:

```
Map hm = new HashMap();
for(int i=0; i<dataArray().length; i++){
    Arraylist valueHashMap = new Arraylist();
    valueHashMap.add(0, aArray[i]);
    valueHashMap.add(1, bArray[i]);
    valueHashMap.add(2, cArray[i]);

    if (hm.containsKey(dArray[i])){
        Arraylist newOne = new Arraylist();
        newOne.add(hm.get(dArray[i]));
        valueHashMap.add(newOne);
        hm.put(dArray[i], valueHashMap);
    }else{
        hm.put(dArray[i], valueHashMap);
    }
}
Iterator iterator = hm.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
String key = iterator.next().toString();
System.out.println(key + " " + hm.get(key));
}
```

Input keys and values are like this:

```
1 : 1, 2, 3
2 : 4, 5, 6
1 : 1, 2, 3
```

The results come out like this:

```
1 : [1, 2, 3, [[1, 2, 3]]]
2 : [4, 5, 6]
```

I want result to come out like this:

```
1 : [2, 4, 6]   //summary of values in arraylist of same key
2 : [4, 5, 6]
```

How should I sum each values in `arraylist` of same key in `hashmap`?

Comment: In your code, hm.containsKey(dArray[i]), you are adding the array to the list. I think this is where you need to SUM the values of the array elements.

Comment: what are `dataArray`, `aArray`, `bArray` and `cArray`

Comment: They are string arrays.

Comment: @Yuki probably show us a trimmed down version of what these arrays contain?

Comment: All of the arrays are contained double values.

Comment: What is trimmed down version?

Answer (score 1):

I think I would've done like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Map<String, int[]> m = new HashMap<>();
    int n = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String[] s = sc.nextLine().split("[,\\s:]+");
        int[] arr = new int[s.length - 1];
        boolean cn = m.containsKey(s[0]);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(s[j + 1]) + ((cn) ? m.get(s[0])[j] : 0);
        }
        m.put(s[0], arr);
    }
    for (String s : m.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(s + " : " + Arrays.toString(m.get(s)));
    }
    sc.close();
```

Input:

```
1 : 1, 2, 3
2 : 4, 5, 6
1 : 1, 2, 3
```

Output:

```
1 : [2, 4, 6]
2 : [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I can't write <>, : symbol.

Comment: @Yuki what? why not?

Comment: I have no idea! I developed Java on websphere studio application developer and Java version is J2RE 1.4.1, Java platform is 5.1.